# Will old Intel copper heat sink fit on new 8th generation CPU?

Tags: processor, intel, heat-sink

I got my hands on an old PC heat sink, intel 775 I think.

Will this fit on my i5-8400 8th gen?

And if it does, what side does it go on?

The copper core is indented on one side and sticks out the other

[image]

[image]

Comment: The side with the copper protruding from the aluminium fins goes on the CPU, otherwise it could not make contact. Normally, these heatsinks come with a mounting mechanism. This -missing- part determines which socket it can fit. One could certainly cobble together a solution to make this work on Socket 1151. It is still missing a fan though, which would normally be attached to / a part of the plastic mounting mechanism. Overall, not worth the effort compared to working solutions starting at 5$ plus shipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't going to fit.

The LGA [775 socket CPUs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_775) are a different form factor, 37.5mm square, than the [i5-8400](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/126687/intel-core-i5-8400-processor-9m-cache-up-to-4-00-ghz.html) which uses an LGA 1151 socket.

The distance between the screw-holes for the heatsink of an LGA 775 is 72 mm. Such heatsinks are not interchangeable with heatsinks for sockets that have a distance of 75 mm, such as the i5-8400 which uses the LGA 1151 socket.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, I asked on Facebook groups, and just got a whole bunch of snotty millenial kids giving me different opinions on this! Great to get an answer from a guy who knows what he's talking about, cheers!